# Particle in Cell: efficient data structure handling

Tags: c++, c++11, simulation

I am building a simulation where you have 'Agents' distributed over a rather large landscape. Because the number of Agents is small, compared to the size of the landscape, I use the PIC approach where the landscape is divided into rather large cells and every cell can contain multiple agents - in contrast to a classical grid based approach. This should speed up spatial analysis.

I am asking whether there is a way to improve the code I came up with:

Agents contain an iterator to the node in the cell and a ptr to the cell containing the node

```
class Agent;

typedef std::list <Agent*> CELL;

class Agent {
  public:
  //...stuff...
    CELL::iterator cell_iter;
    CELL*cell_ptr;
};

class Grid {
  public:
    Grid(int dimx,int dimy,int cellsize);
    CELL *GetCell(double x,double y); 
 private:
    std::vector <std::vector<CELL>> grid_;
    int dimx_,dimy_,cellsize_,ncellx_,ncelly_;  
};
```

To add a new individual:

```
std::list <Agent> population;
//..stuff...
Agent seed(pos_x,pos_y,seed_type,10.1); // create a local agent
population.push_back(std::move(seed));
Agent *agent=&population.back()
CELL *cell=GetCell(agent->x_,agent->y_); // get the cell for the agents pos
cell->push_back(agent); // add the agents ptr to the cell
agent->cell_ptr=cell; // save the agents cell to the agent
agent->cell_iter=--cell->end(); // save an iterator to the actual node
```

To delete an individual

```
auto iter=population.begin();
//...stuff...
(*iter).cell_ptr->erase((*iter).cell_iter); // erase the ptr to the agent from the cell
iter=population.erase(iter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have move `push_back` then you should also have `emplace_back`.

```
population.emplace_back(pos_x,pos_y,seed_type,10.1);
```

Erasing the individual means moving everyone that comes after. If you don't care about order then do a swap with back:

```
auto iter=population.begin();
//...stuff...
(*iter).cell_ptr->erase((*iter).cell_iter); // erase the ptr to the agent from the cell
std::swap(*iter, population.back());
population.pop_back();
//doesn't invalidate iter
```

Comment: thanks for the "emplace_back" trick. why is the swap faster?

Comment: @SebastianLehmann it only needs to copy 1 element over instead of half. The swap is a `O(1)` operation while the simple erase is `O(n)`

Comment: i thought erase is guarantied to be O(1) and remove is O(n)

Comment: @SebastianLehmann [Complexity: Linear in distance between pos and the end of the container.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)